# Значение букв

Tags: русская-графика

похозяйничать (ововоооооово), Алешкой(воооово), никто (ооооо), ни бабушка (оо оооооов), ни мама (оо оооо)
о - основное значение, в -второстепенное значение.

Comment: O_o?!
Что это было?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

похозяйничать (ововоооооооо),  ни бабушка (оо оооооов), ни мама (оо ооов)